# Delete rows in a table that don't match rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

*I'm aware this question has been asked before, but the solutions given assume an id (single-column) relationship.  I've tried adapting, but the given solutions aren't working for my case.*

**Update:** I must have had my head so far up my own butt that I got turned around.  Reviewing the documentation and other code, I see my question and intent should have been to "delete rows in a table that *DO* match rows in another table."  That question is much easier to answer, and I have it working.

I have 2 MySQL INNODB tables - `clas` and `clas_import` - that have a few columns in common.  I'm importing a CSV into `clas_import` and I want to delete any rows in `clas` that don't exist in `clas_import`.

`clas_import` is defined like this:

```
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| term      | smallint(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject   | varchar(10)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| catalog   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| component | varchar(10)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| section   | varchar(5)           | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`clas` has many more columns, but the `id`,`term`, etc columns are defined identical to above.

A unique "class" is defined by a combination of `term` + `subject` + `catalog` + `component` + `section`.  So I want to find all entries in `clas` that don't match up to an entry in `clas_import`, and delete it.  The added kicker is that not *all* rows are being compared - only those where the `term` row matches certain values

**Example data:**

`clas_import`

```
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id | term | subject | catalog | component | section |
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | 1730 | ENG     |     102 | LEC       | 1A04    |
| 15 | 1730 | BLA     |     102 | LEC       | 1A04    |
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

`clas` (columns truncated to only show relevant data)

```
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| id | term | subject | catalog | component | section |
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| 23 | 1730 | ENG     |     102 | LEC       | 1A04    |
| 26 | 1730 | BLA     |     102 | LEC       | 1A04    |
| 30 | 1730 | ENG     |     100 | LEC       | 1A04    |
| 11 | 1700 | ENG     |     102 | LEC       | 1A04    |
+----+------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

**Desired result:**
That I can run a query and have row #23 & #26 deleted, while leaving row #30 and #11 untouched.

**My query:**

```sql
DELETE
    FROM `clas`
WHERE
    `clas`.`term` IN (1730) AND
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `clas_import` as `ci`
        WHERE
            `clas`.`term`      = `ci`.`term` AND
            `clas`.`subject`   = `ci`.`subject` AND
            `clas`.`catalog`   = `ci`.`catalog` AND
            `clas`.`component` = `ci`.`component` AND
            `clas`.`section`   = `ci`.`section`
        )
```

That query doesn't delete anything.  When I change `DELETE` to `SELECT *`, no rows are returned.  Both the tables are populated, and if I do a simple query matching on the `term`,`subject`, etc, I get rows returned - so I know the data is good.

Where is this breaking down?

**Edit** Here's a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6cfd81899fbacb5e567ec84d6e5ed7d6

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @GMB because I misspoke.  Thanks - I'll fix that.

Comment: Are the fields' datatypes the same between the two tables? Have you verified string fields in either table aren't concealing whitespace or even non-printing characters? Do the string fields have the same collation?

Comment: @Uueero - the relevant fields are identical.  `clas_import` was made by copying `clas`.

Comment: I'd provide `show create table xyz` outputs for both tables as `desc xyz` does not give all information required. As per 'fields are identical' -- someone might change it. You might change it and forgot. You might slightly modified it while creating. Many options possible so I'd better provide the proof.

Comment: BTW, my bet it is whitespaces. May be not spaces but something like \r. If you provide details what (sql? csv? xml?) and how (exact options if it is load data command) you import your data it may give us some clues.

Comment: You can start checking with manually entered values: `SELECT * FROM clas WHERE term = '1730' AND subject = 'ENG' AND catalog = 102 AND component = 'LEC' AND section = '1A04'` and then do the same for clas_import.

Comment: @fifonik Good point. If it's a Windows file with \r\n newlines imported onto Unix with \n newlines there might be a trailing \r in the last field.

Comment: @fifonik There's no one else that works on this server, and I just checked the table definitions before posting, so I'm extremely confident the tables are the same (not 100% because humans make errors).  I'm importing the file into `clas_import`, then transferring data from `clas_import` to `clas`.  I'll look into the whitespace issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @fifonik Thanks for your attention to my question.  As I've just updated - my problem was actually the exact opposite of what I posted.  Thanks again for your help, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

[Your query works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d3ecee9bc03e7b7332ba25b853ac7543), there's something else going on. My first guess would be to check for whitespace differences.

But I only just realized that after writing the answer, so here's how you'd do it a bit cleaner.

---

You want a [left excluding join](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) to match only the rows in `clas` which do not match rows in `clas_import`.

[image]

```
delete clas
from clas
left join clas_import ci on
            clas.term      = ci.term AND
            clas.subject   = ci.subject AND
            clas.catalog   = ci.catalog AND
            clas.component = ci.component AND
            clas.section   = ci.section
      -- This bit makes it exclusive.
where ci.id is null and
      -- And ignore other terms.
      clas.term = 1730;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=27fe7913dba63f8b75e6887c0b3f8499)

Comment: Thanks.  This format isn't working just the same as the one I posted.  But your answer is so clear that I agree with you - I must have something else going on.

Comment: @fifonik Thanks for your attention to my question.  As I've just updated - my problem was actually the exact opposite of what I posted.  Thanks again for your help, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

By using the sample data in your question and the table definitions in your fiddle, I got the result that you want by removing `NOT` from `EXISTS`, so I guess your logic was wrong:

```
DELETE
    FROM `clas`
WHERE
    `clas`.`term` IN (1730) AND
    EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `clas_import` as `ci`
        WHERE
            `clas`.`term`      = `ci`.`term` AND
            `clas`.`subject`   = `ci`.`subject` AND
            `clas`.`catalog`   = `ci`.`catalog` AND
            `clas`.`component` = `ci`.`component` AND
            `clas`.`section`   = `ci`.`section`
        )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ff6c253d7d2d0330f93c4139aaabedc2).
Results:

```
> id | term | subject | catalog | component | section
> -: | ---: | :------ | ------: | :-------- | :------
> 11 | 1700 | ENG     |     102 | LEC       | 1A04   
> 30 | 1730 | ENG     |     100 | LEC       | 1A04
```

Comment: Thanks.  The solution ended up not needing a subquery at all - just some plain WHERE conditions.